# Fill in boundries detected using Canny

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am a beginner in digital image processing and i have a CT lung image that i have detected each lung outer boundary using Canny. Now i just want to "fill" in the boundaries with ones so that i have the mask matrix for the lungs for further processing inside them. I am trying to use a for loop  but its still complex to iterate inside the boundary ,so any suggestions guys ? Here is the image:

CT segmented using Canny
[image: CT segmented using Canny]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you use Canny here, rather than simply thresholding? The lungs are black in CT, they are easy to distinguish based on intensity.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fill the holes. This is accomplished with the [`imfill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) function of the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
BW2 = imfill(BW,'holes');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately the imfill() doesn't fully fill the lungs.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed OK, so what do you see and what do you expect to see? "Doesn't work" is not a useful statement. Edit your question to add more detail.